# Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl Chapter 7.1.3 - Failing Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've spent a couple hours trying to figure out this tiny little piece of the puzzle before moving on in the tutorial so it doesn't blow up on my later.  Because of that, I know issues where tests are failing like these are a dime a dozen, so I apologize. In the "7.1.3 Testing the user show page (with factories)" section of the tutorial (link provided below), I cannot get the signup page tests to pass.  This seems like it's so trivial, but I can't find anything wrong in any of the seemingly endless files where there could be an issue (the controller, routes, the test itself, the user model, and so on).   No one online seems to have had this issue either, so I figure it's got to be some random setting or something on my rails project.

Anyway, here is what I believe is the relevant code:
**The error from running the user_pages_spec test in sublime:**

```
Failures:

  1) User pages signup page 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_content('Sign up') }
       expected #has_content?("Sign up") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User pages signup page 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }
       expected #has_title?("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Sign up") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.16194 seconds
4 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:18 # User pages signup page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:19 # User pages signup page 

Randomized with seed 46255

[Finished in 2.7s with exit code 1]
```

**spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_content(user.name) }
    it { should have_title(user.name) }
  end

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign up') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }
  end
end
```

**app/views/users/new.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign Up') %>
<h1>Sign Up</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/users/new.html.erb</p>
```

**app/controller/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
  end
end
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  root to: 'static_pages#home'
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
end
```

Let me know if you can think of any other code you may need to see.  I included new.html.erb because *I think* that the signup test is looking on that page, but I must be wrong on that.  If anyone could let me know what I'm doing wrong that is causing this failure, I would be eternally grateful.

If you could convince me that the whole test driven development concept isn't a complete pain in the rear, then you could get some extra brownie points on top of that.  I've found this tutorial to be pretty enjoyable, but any time I get to a testing section I lose all motivation to continue, especially when it doesn't work.  I know it's better for your code in the long run, but for just getting started I'm beginning to think I should just ignore it at risk of quitting.

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial?version=4.0#code-name_title_and_heading

Comment: What happens if you replace one of your signup tests with: `it "foo" do; save_and_open_page; subject.should have_content('Sign up'); end`

Comment: Do you have a users_controller.rb file?  The tests (when written correctly) are telling you there's something wrong with your code.  That may be annoying, but a lot less annoying than an end-user email telling you the same thing...

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta, That test fails.

Comment: @PinnyM, Good point, and I will update my post with my controller file, which I think is just how it is in the tutorial

Comment: Can you check what `response.body` actually contains to help shed some light on what the controller thinks it should render?

Comment: @PinnyM, What do you mean by the response.body?  I pasted everything from the error thrown by rspec, and I pasted everything that is in my controller.  New to rails, so excuse my lack of knowledge on this, I have a feeling it's probably something pretty standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to replace 'Sign up' by 'Sign Up' in your **spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb** ?

Comment: Oh... my.. goodness... I feel so stupid.  I've been programming for several years and I looked through my code multiple times, and for some reason never thought to try that.  The test code is exactly like it is in the guide, so maybe he had a typo too.  Anyways, I love you @FloRahl.  This has caused me days of anguish and all because of a lowercase U

Comment: Ah ah ! I met so many times the same problem ! Syntactical errors are my best ability :-) Happy to have been of some help.